# Ninject: can't register generic interface to many other interfaces

Tags: c#, generics, ninject

I'm trying to register a generic interface in Ninject, and then I want to some other interface to that generic interface:

```
public interface ISE<T> { }

public class SE<T> : ISE<T> { }

public interface IConcreteSE_A : ISE<SomeClass_A> { }
public interface IConcreteSE_B : ISE<SomeClass_B> { }
public interface IConcreteSE_C : ISE<SomeClass_C> { }


kernel.Bind(typeof(ISE<>)).To(typeof(SE<>));
kernel.Bind<IConcreteSE_A>().To(typeof(SE<>));
kernel.Bind<IConcreteSE_B>().To(typeof(SE<>));
kernel.Bind<IConcreteSE_C>().To(typeof(SE<>));
```

But I get an error: **The number of generic arguments given is not equal to the number of general type definition arguments** when I try to inject e.g. `IConcreteSE_A` to my web api controller.

how to fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because there is no implicit reference conversion between `IConcreteSE_A` and `ISE<SomeClass_A>`. In other words there is no guarantee that `SE<SomeClass_A>`, which implements `ISE<SomeClass_A>`, actually satisfies the implementation for `IConcreteSE_A`.

You can fix this by creating a concrete class that implements both interfaces and then bind to that.

```
public class SE<T> : ISE<T> { }
public class SomeClassA { }
public class ConcreteSE_A : ISE<SomeClass_A>, IConcreteSE_A { }

public interface IConcreteSE_A : ISE<SomeClass_A> { }

kernel.Bind(typeof(ISE<>)).To(typeof(SE<>));
kernel.Bind<IConcreteSE_A>().To<ConcreteSE_A>();
```